# CSS selector with element between two classes

Tags: jquery, css

Want to know what jQuery selector to use for selecting  with class "bar" ONLY if it is under a button element (no class) which in turn, is under a div with class "foo"

```
<div class="foo">
  <button>
    <i class="bar">X</i>
 ...
```

".foo button.bar" doesn't work

EDITED: Thanks for all the solutions, tried the solution but for some reason the following gets selected too:

```
<div id="mceu_36" class="mce-widget mce-btn mce-first" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="mceu_36" role="button" aria-label="Align left">
  <button role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1">
    <i class="mce-ico mce-i-dashicon dashicons-align-left"></i>
  </button>
</div>
...
<div id="mceu_40" class="mce-widget mce-btn" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="mceu_40" role="button" aria-label="Edit ">
  <button role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1">
    <i class="mce-ico mce-i-dashicon dashicons-edit"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```

My intention is to handle click on `<i>` with dashicons-edit class ONLY if it is under div with mce-first. In the above example, "mce-first" is on a sibling div.

Comment: So what are you using to target the `i.dashicons-edit` element that isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To comply explicitly with your requirements:

- selecting `<i>` with class "bar"
- ONLY if it is under a button element (no class)
- which in turn, is under a div with class "foo"

You'll want this selector

```
div.foo > button:not([class]) > i.bar
```

In selector syntax, a space indicates any level below in the DOM hierarchy. The `>` operator indicates a direct child.

If you don't necessarily want direct-child selection, just use spaces

```
div.foo button:not([class]) i.bar
```

If you're not particularly interested in the elements (other than `<button>`) and don't care what classes may or may not be on the `<button>`, simply use

```
.foo button .bar
```

---

Your selector `.foo button.bar` was looking for a `<button>` with class `bar` that was any level below an element with class `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use find to check if there are so many target elements inside foo.

```
$('.foo').find('button .bar');
```

Answer (score 0):

> ".foo button.bar" doesn't work

`button.bar` mean button element has class `bar`

the HTML look like this

```
<div class="foo">
  <button class="bar">
    <i class="bar">X</i>
```

Correct:
`.foo button .bar`